# Display users' images in Django

Tags: django, image, file-upload

I am learning Django and currently trying to make a simple website where users can post topics and stuff. What I want is only the uploaded images that belong to a certain topic to display when you open the topic. But I am so stuck at it now I can't get any image come up on the pages. I've tried many different things but none's worked so far. I can't get my head around how exactly the template should look like and how do I link it to the topic page...and my view is probably far from right but I've tried a lot of things and it's all got a bit messy...pretty much it's been 2 days of  hassle and I will appreciate any directions
Thank you in advance

This is what i have:

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    """images representation"""
    image=models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to= 'media/')
    caption=models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    uploaded_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def upload_image(request, topic_id):
    """Upload images"""
    topic=Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)


    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; creaete a blank form
        form=ImageForm()

    else:
        # Data submitted; Process data
        form=ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance=form.save(commit=FALSE)
            instance.topic=topic
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('the_horror:topic',
                                                args=[topic_id]))

    images=Image.objects.all()      
    context={'form':form, 'topic':topic, 'images':images}
    return render(request, 'the_horror/topic.html', context)
```

upload_image.html

```html
{% extends 'the_horror/base.html' %}


{% block content %}

{% if images %}
 <ul>
 {% for image in images %}
  <li>
   <a href="{{image.image.url}}">
            <img source="{{image.image.url}}" alt="sth"></a>
  </li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% else %}
 <p>No documents.</p>
{% endif %}


<form action="{% url 'upload_image' %}" method= "post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
    <button type="submit">name="upload photo"</button>
</form>
```

As i said i am not sure how to pass the images to the topic template

topic.html

```html
{% extends 'the_horror/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<p>Topic:{{topic}}</p>
 <p>
  <a href="{% url 'the_horror:edit_topic' topic.id %)">edit topic</a>
 </p>
  
 
<p>Entries</p>
 <p>
  <a href="{% url 'the_horror:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add a new entry</a>
 </p>
<ul>
 {% for entry in entries %}
  <li>
   <p>{{entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
   <p>{{entry.text|linebreaks}}</p>
   <p>
    <image class= "Image" source={{>
   </p>
  
   <p>
    <a href="{% url 'the_horror:edit_entry' entry.id %}">edit entry</a>
   </p>
    </li>
 {% empty %}
  <li> 
   There are no entries for this topic yet.
  </li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
 
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
path('upload_image/<topic_id>', views.upload_image, name= 'upload_image'),
# Single topic page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your models.py you don't need to write media on your upload_to option, what you have to do is to add to your urls.py `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` here

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

On your upload_image.html why are you creating 2 input. Personally I use an input to take the image file

**upload_image.html**

```
...
<input name="image" type="file">
...
```

then in the views you started well but I will do as follow to store the image

**views.py**

```
def upload_image(request, topic_id):
    ...
    imageObject = Image.objects.create()
    image = request.FILES['image']
    imageObject.image = image
    ...
```

Finally, you will get your image this way

**topic.html**

```
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{imageObject.image}}" alt="image">
```

Usually it works, I made several projects with this method or similar methods, if you still got error or question let me know

Comment: Cheers for that! Yeah, apparently this is one method to do it  I saw it in ' Django related objects etc' as well but unfortunately for me still can't make it work. All I get is a little 'x' where the image should display. And still I don't think I have the whole 'topic: image' working properly... But to be fare I really want just to get an image to show for a start. What do you think that 'x' is about and in the views.py the way you showed it to me what wuold you put as a context? I mean...(topic:topic, image:topic...). Cheers

Comment: Please make sure that you get all the above informations :
1 - media folder out of the app folder
2.1 - on settings.py be sure to have the absolute path of your media folder on a variable named like this `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, 'media/')`
2.2 - still on settings.py configure your MEDIA_URL as follow `MEDIA_URL = '/media'`
Doing this you will, usually, be able to store and use images.
Personally, on my views, I just use locals() instead of context because I always wanted all my datas from the views
Please let me know if it still doesn't work and I will try to help you